# Need to know how to retrieve a nested data from firebase in Angular 8

Tags: firebase, angular-material, angular8

So I'm creating a CRM system using Firebase real Time DB and Angular ~8.2.8. I have been able to so far get to adding a new customer, viewing a customer, and editing a customer. The issue I am having is viewing a nested array within the Angular DB List.

For example i have a customer, within that customer i have left actions and right actions. Those actions are selected via a dropdown menu. The repair actions are defined as A1, A2, A3, A4 etc and you can select multiple repair actions.

CRM database Example

- Customer List

  - First_Name
  - Last_Name
  - Left_Repair_Actions

    1. 0: "A1"
    2. 1: "A2"
    3. 2: "A3"
    4. 3: "A4"
  - Right_Repair_Actions

    1. 0: "A1"
    2. 1: "A2"
    3. 2: "A3"
    4. 3: "A4"

Im creating this database for a hearing aid company, who needs different repair actions for both hearing aids. The reason having the repair action on the table is important because the employees can see quickly what repair action was done to the hearing aid without having to open up the customer file.

//Here is where I defined the array

```
 RepairActions: string[] = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'];
```

//Over here is the HTML section where i called on the array so i can select the repair action for the right side

```
  <!-- Customer Right Repair Action-->
                <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-label>Left Repair Action Aid Type</mat-label>
                        <mat-select [(value)]="selectedLeftRepairAction" multiple formControlName="left_repair_actions">
                            <mat-option [value]="repairLeftActionType" *ngFor="let repairLeftActionType of RepairActions">
                                {{repairLeftActionType}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="handleError('right_repair_actions', 'required')">
                            Right Repair Action is required
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

//HTML of the customer table list that will not show the correct value

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="right_repair_actions">
                <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Right Repair Actions </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.right_repair_actions}} </td>
            </ng-container>
```

//Her is the TS file for the table

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Customer>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;
  CustomerData: any = [];
  displayedColumns: any[] = [
    'repair_date',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'warranty',
    'warranty_ends',
    'left_repair_actions',
    'right_repair_actions',
    'phone',
    'action'
  ];


constructor(private customerApi: CustomerService) {
this.customerApi.GetCustomerList()
  .snapshotChanges().subscribe(customers => {
    customers.forEach(item => {
      let a = item.payload.toJSON();
      a['$key'] = item.key;
      this.CustomerData.push(a as Customer)
    })
    /* Data table */
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.CustomerData);
    /* Pagination */
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
        switch (property) {
          case 'repair_date': {
            return new Date(item.repair_date);
          }
          default: return item[property];
        }
      };
    }, 0);
  })
```

Just shows object object in the table and wont show the values like A1, A5, A6 like i want it. [RepairActionExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbors.png)